# How to find which contenttype causing error?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, content-type

I am  trying to export the site. but it is failing at one contenttype. How to find that contenttype and delete it from the site?

```
    [11/24/2014 4:36:13 PM] [Folder] [Page Layout] Progress: Exporting /_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/Page Layout
[11/24/2014 4:36:13 PM] Progress: Finished processing objects of type Folder.
[11/24/2014 4:36:13 PM] Progress: Starting to process objects of type ContentType.
[11/24/2014 4:36:13 PM] FatalError: Field type ContentTypeIdFieldType is not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete this field. 
[11/24/2014 4:36:13 PM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPFieldFromSafeArray(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.CreateSPField(Int32 ifld)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureSPField(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.ItemAtIndex(Int32 iIndex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.get_Fields()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ContentTypeSerializer.GetDataFromDataSet(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.SerializeObject(Object obj, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, String elementName, Boolean bNeedEnvelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object topLevelObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.SerializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.Run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The content type name is already in the error message `ContentTypeIdFieldType`. You can delete it by going to the `Site Settings -> Site Content Type(under Galleries) -> Search and Select the content type`.

But, this may not help you, because it seems to be used in some list. So, even if you delete this content type, you may continue getting this error. In case if you have only few lists, you can check and delete the culprit field manually. Refer to the answer of [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2098/how-do-i-determine-where-a-content-type-is-being-used) question if you have lot of lists to deal with.